# sendtoaddress command doesn't work with bech32 bitcoin core 0.17

Tags: bitcoin-core, bech32-address

I have bitcoin-core 0.17 working on `regtest` mode and when I try to send to a bech32 testnet address I get invalid address

I have set `addresstype=bech32` on my bitcoin.conf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the wrong address type for the network that you are on. Regtest bech32 addresses begin with "bcrt".